# Find Heroku custom domains using node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

In Heroku, is there a way to retrieve the list of custom domains as specified in the Heroku app settings using Node.js?

ie - these:

[image]

process or process.env doesn't provide these:

```
process.???
process.env.???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a platform API call using [node-heroku-client](https://github.com/jclem/node-heroku-client):

```
var Heroku = require('heroku-client');
var heroku = new Heroku({ token: process.env.HEROKU_API_TOKEN });
var app = heroku.apps('my-app');
app.domains().list(function (err, domains) {
  // List of the app's `domains`
});
```

API reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain